# Layer "model" expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors

Tags: multimodal

I built a vqa model, and set two inputs(images, questions).
It was well trained with train/val datasets, but with test_dataset, it keep printing errors like below;

```
ValueError: Layer "model" expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(224, 224, 3) dtype=float32>]
```

The variables I used are;

[test_qt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwaWv.png)

[test_it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9ep1.png)

test_qt and test_it are both lists of tensors..

I built a dataset with this code;

```
test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_it, test_qt))
```

I also tried to directly give each input separately but got this error.

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 224, 224, 302, 302
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
```